# Best practice for managing assets in a desktop c# NET application

Tags: c#, .net, assets

My app is targeted at desktop machine, and it depends on an excel file for some initialization data. I chose excel because I will be continually adding data in the development phase and it gives me a powerful environment to curate the data.

What is the best practice to associate the excel file with the app so it is always found at run time?

I could

a) assume it resides in the same directory as the app and make sure the installer puts it there
b) put it in a set place relative to the executable, and once again have the installer put it there
c) Use an environment variable to point to the location of the file
d) pass the path of the file to the app on launch

None of these seem quite right. I'd like a fire-and-forget method that never loses track of the file - much like accessing game resources in an android or ios app, where they can be "baked-in" to the bundle and referenced in a consistent way.

Is there such a pattern in the c#/NET/desktop environment? Or an equivalent?

Comment: Embed as resource. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292

Comment: I would use a combination of things just for versatility. Go with embedded resource but I would leave a back door where you can specify the file path in the app settings (or app.config) and then you can decide if you want the installer to add the file in a set location on install (maybe handy for click once apps)

Comment: What I do is typically bundle the empty data file with the program as part of the installation process. When the program starts it tests if there is a copy of the file in the program's data area via Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData). If not, it copies the empty file from the installation folder. So the empty Excel file you install in your installation folder is only used once to "prime" the actual file that will be used. Or maybe used again if a different user logs on to the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the application initialization data we used are residing in json or XML based files. Also, when the application starts, we cache these in memory and re-read on app restarts

Ideally the database would be a preferred option. In SQL 2014, we do have in memory tables that are more efficient.

Regarding the locations, you should have the values from appsettings from app.config / web.config.

The excel files are not suitable for all environment like andriod, where as JSON is universally accepted standard.

Being less dependant on external apps like excel will be preferred, as all installation cannot contain Microsoft office installed, unless you use openxmlsdk.

Comment: Yes, I agree. In my description I alluded to the fact I was using the excel file in development. When things stabilize, I'll switch to XML